# How to convert JSON with backwordslash

Tags: json, serialization

I have `JSON` like  this

```
var myVariable=[{"items": "SOFT TOUCH AVOCADO 125 ML x 6D","descriptions": "100mg","umo": "CTN","qty": 1,"price": 0,"lineamount": 0,"customerid": "ANG001","tdate": "11:0:2015","orderId": "Himansu12:9:707","bookorder": "ABCANG00197","FOC": 1}];
```

But We need JSON like this

```
 var stringtwo ="[{\"items\": 19760,\"descriptions\": 7,\"umo\": 18377,\"qty\":8,\"price\":8,\"lineamount\": \"22\" ,\"customerid\": 1960,\"tdate\": 7,\"orderId\": 1377,\"bookorder\":7,\"FOC\":7 }]";
```

so Please any one guide me how to convert JSON (myVaiable) to JSON (stringtwo).We Try to POST data to server. Webservice developed by `.NET`.SO We need POST JSON (stringtwo).But We Get JSON (myVaiable).

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://183.82.0.221:1234/MyService.svc/PostOrderData/'+stringone+','+stringtwo+'',
            dataType:'jsonp',
            type:'get',
            cache:false,
            timeout: 2000,
            error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t=="timeout") {
            alert("this app need internet connection so Please connect net first ");

        } else {
            //alert(t);
        }},
          success:function(data) {
                debugger;
    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
    },
});
```

We tried JSON data post to Server.but we got 400 bad request.

Comment: Your question is very unclear and confusing. Please show more what did you try, and explain what would `stringtwo` be used for.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch webservices developed by some one he need if i post json data to server with backslashes.Please look my code

Comment: Why the `type:'get'` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch in services he using Get

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You just want to serialize in a [JSON](http://json.org/) string. Read more about [JSON in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

So use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like

```
var stringtwo = JSON.stringify(myVariable)
```

(BTW, you are lacking a *Javascript* tag)

Notice that you might use it multiply (but I can't guess why you would want to do that), for instance

```
var stringthree = JSON.stringify(stringtwo)
```

and even perhaps

```
var stringfour = JSON.stringify(stringthree)
```

etc

you could later call [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://some.url/goes/here",
         type: 'POST',
         data: stringfour, // but more probably stringtwo or stringthree
         success: function (gotdata) {
         }
         /// etc
       })
```

Read also about [string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) & [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Comment: thanks for reply.but when i convert it's not add back-word  slashes  in stringtwo

Comment: There are no backslashes. The literal string token for a string is not the string.

Comment: webservices developed by some one he need if i post json data to server with backslashes.Please look my code

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your object as JSON string and replace `"` with `\"`

```js
// SiwachGaurav's version from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript
function stringReplaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&'),'g'),replace);
}

var myVariable = [{"items": "SOFT TOUCH AVOCADO 125 ML x 6D","descriptions": "100mg","umo": "CTN","qty": 1,"price": 0,"lineamount": 0,"customerid": "ANG001","tdate": "11:0:2015","orderId": "Himansu12:9:707","bookorder": "ABCANG00197","FOC": 1}];

var stringtwo = stringReplaceAll(JSON.stringify(myVariable), '\"', '\\"');

// stringtwo becomes "[{\"items\":\"SOFT TOUCH AVOCADO 125 ML x 6D\",\"descriptions\":\"100mg\",\"umo\":\"CTN\",\"qty\":1,\"price\":0,\"lineamount\":0,\"customerid\":\"ANG001\",\"tdate\":\"11:0:2015\",\"orderId\":\"Himansu12:9:707\",\"bookorder\":\"ABCANG00197\",\"FOC\":1}]"
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xmojmr/v6b5ma9n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick I've used to do what you are asking (requires Intellij IDEA - not sure if Eclipse will do this).  Also, assuming this is a once off, not part of a repeating process:

In any Java file, do this:

```
String json "";
```

Now, put the JSON that does not include the backslashes on the clipboard.  Position the cursor between the quotes.  Paste.  Voila. Your JSON is escaped exactly as you requested.